# Is this code correct for a Re-direct on Cloud Pages in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, cloudpage

After form submission, if the person opted out, I want them to go to the Yahoo URL. Otherwise, I want them to go to Google. Do I have any extra `<body>` tags, should I take them out?

```
</head>
<body>
%%[ if @HasOptedOutOfEmail == "true" then ]%%
<body>
%%=redirect(‘https://www.yahoo.com/')=%%
%%[else]%%
%%=redirect('https://www.google.com/')=%%
</body>
%%[endif]%%
</body>
```

Comment: You don’t need the body tags in there at all, but what kind of problem are you facing exactly? Is this the form handler CloudPage?

Comment: I haven't entered it yet so no problem. Ampscript is not my strong suit so I want to make sure I am not developing bad habits. So I can take out all the body tags and the form will still be submitted and then re-directed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s easier if you just put this into one block:

```
%%[
if @HasOptedOutOfEmail == "on" then 
redirect(‘https://www.yahoo.com/')
else
redirect('https://www.google.com/')
endif
]%%
```

If your field is a checkbox, use the condition `if @HasOptedOutOfEmail == "on"` because that’s the value that a checkbox will evaluate to. If it’s a different kind of input, change it back to `true`.

But whether it will get submitted or not, that depends on the rest of your code, which you didn’t include in your question. I suggest giving it a try and opening a new question in case you get stuck.

Here are some resources to help you understand how to work with forms in AMPscript:

https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/

https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/

Here is the example script from the [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/) with a redirect added for your reference:

```
%%[

if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then

  InsertData(
        "Registrations",
        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
        "Email", RequestParameter("email")
       )

set @HasOptedOutOfEmail = RequestParameter(“optout”)

if @HasOptedOutOfEmail == "on" then 
    redirect(‘https://www.yahoo.com/')
    else
    redirect('https://www.google.com/')
    endif

endif

]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      %%[ if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then ]%%
         <p>Thank you for submitting your details.</p>
      %%[ else ]%%
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>First name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname">
         <label>Last name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <label>Company</label>
         <input type="text" name="company">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="email">
         <label>Opt Out</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="optout"/>
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      %%[ endif ]%%
   </body>
</html>
```